# How can I plot the reciprocal of a value in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, graphite

How can I plot the `1/series` in Grafana? The [docs](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#module-graphite.render.functions) show `scale`, which allows multiplying by a constant, and `divideSeries` which allows you to divide two series by each other, but there doesn't seem to be a way to divide a constant by a series.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround would be to  add second query constantLine(1) then add a third query that divide the second by the first then hide the first 2 queries and you should be good to go with the third query.

Answer (score -1):

Grafana supports the `invert` function, as described in the [docs](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.invert).

> "Takes one metric or a wildcard seriesList, and inverts each datapoint (i.e. 1/x)."

This is the example from the documentation:

```
&target=invert(Server.instance01.threads.busy)
```